# Not writing to AD Attribute with variables, manual ok

Tags: powershell, csv

I can run the command :
set-aduser -identity ktest -employeeid 1292921 and it works great.

my csv file :

```
employeeid  Name
9089809890  ktest
```

Try to run this, and it does not work.

```
$stuff = Import-Csv c:\temp\finalexport_test.txt
$stuff

$empid = $stuff.employeeid
$userid = $stuff.name

foreach ($user in $userid) {
    Set-ADUser -Identity $user -EmployeeID $empid
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your csv isn't really comma delimited. For two space delimited, try something like this:

```
$stuff = Import-Csv -Delimiter "  " -Path c:\temp\finalexport_test.txt
```

If it was tab delimited:

```
$stuff = Import-Csv -Delimiter "`t" -Path c:\temp\finalexport_test.txt
```

Comment: I saw that .. that is exactly what I found.